# Lie derivative is the lie bracket

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading the proof of the equivalence between the Lie derivative and the Lie bracket.
We define the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_X Y$ as $F'(0)$ where $F(t)=\Phi_{{-t}_{*\Phi_t(p)}}(Y_ {{\Phi_t(p)}})$ and $\Phi_t$ is the local flow of $X$ in a neighbourhood of $X$.

The proof is separated in cases. I don't understand the case where $X(p)=0$ but $X$ is not identically zero. The author says that there is a continuity argument over $[X,Y]$ and $\mathcal{L}_X Y$ that proves the result, but which is that argument?

Comment: What text are you following? The proof of this fact that I am familiar with doesn't break into multiple cases.

Comment: @yousufsoliman I do not know a reference for this proof, but the idea is the following: $(1)$ Assume that $X$ is non-vanishing at $p$, then using the [straightening theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightening_theorem_for_vector_fields), it suffices to prove the result for $X=\partial/\partial x$, $(2)$ Assume that $X$ is identically zero in a neighborhood of $p$, then $\mathcal{L}_XY=0=[X,Y]$ and $(3)$ this is the question of the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is not identically vanishing, there exists $(p_i)_{i}$ a sequence of points converging toward $p$ such that: 
$$X(p_i)\neq 0.$$
According to a *probably* previous case of the proof you are reading, one has:
$$\mathcal{L}_{X}Y(p_i)=[X,Y](p_i).$$
Now, $\mathcal{L}_XY$ and $[X,Y]$ are smooth, whence the result taking $i\to+\infty$.